# background color and font color transition

Tags: css

I know how i can change bg-color and font color with transition in css3:

```
/**Background color transition**/
-webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
-o-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
transition: background-color 300ms linear;

/**Font color transition**/
-webkit-transition-property:color, text;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-moz-transition-property:color, text;
-moz-transition-duration:1s;
-moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;

-o-transition-property:color, text;
-o-transition-duration:1s;
-o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
```

My question is, i can set two transitions (bg and font color) in same class?
Thanks!.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use short hand transitions as follows if you want to combine them:

**CSS**

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear, color 1s linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 300ms linear, color 1s linear;
-o-transition: background-color 300ms linear, color 1s linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear, color 1s linear;
transition: background-color 300ms linear, color 1s linear;
```

Comment: You can combine them without using the shorthand too. `transition-property: background-color, color`, `transition-duration: 300ms, 300ms` etc.